# Two superimposing plots with one having no fill

Tags: python, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray, scatter-plot, cartopy

Goal: -

1- Scatter datapoints `csatlat` and `csatlon` with a `c=cloudlayerheight` argument, the `cloudlayerheight` has some masked values.
`cloudlayerheight.shape=(36950,)`,
`len(csatlat)=len(csatlon)=36950`.
For this I'm getting this plot
[image: Cloud thickness plot]

As you can see, there are some gaps in the plot for which `cloudlayerheight` has masked values. I'd like to have a boundary over the whole plot, i.e. Have those gaps filled by two lines with no fill. I'm aiming for this[image: Target plot].

This is to show the path traced by the satellite.

2- Have a no fill boundary cover the entire track of satellite, so that the `cloudlayerheight` plot is visible.

What I have tried

```
plot=ax.scatter(csatlon,csatlat,c=cloudlayerheight,s=5,
norm=divnorm, 
cmap='jet',
transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()) #1st plot

#For the boundary plot
ax.scatter(csatlon,csatlat,
edgecolors='black',
facecolors='none',
transform=ccrs.PlateCarree());
```

But I am getting this result, which is not useful

[image: Result that I am getting]

Increasing the value of `s` argument for boundary plot is not working as it's not opaque in the inside, it's swallowing the first plot. I can't select a `hline` marker shape, because it throws `positional argument follows keyword argument` error.

Comment: Maybe you could change the order? First plotting the black dots, and afterwards the colored ones? You could also experiment with the z-order. E.g. `ax.scatter(...., zorder=2)` for the black dots and  `ax.scatter(...., zorder=3)` for the colored ones.

Comment: @JohanC The first method worked. Thank you.